# Switching to ZSH Bricked My Mac Mini

Tags: reboot, zsh

I'm running Unbutu 18.04 on a Mac Mini with a single boot (i.e., no MacOS image). I wanted to switch to the zsh shell. I ran the command:

> sudo apt-get install zsh

I then ran:

> zsh --version

and saw the version 5.4.2. Next, I ran

> whereis zsh

I picked a location and ran:

> sudo usermod -s /bin/zsh $(whoami)

I then ran

> sudo reboot

The OS won't come up. When I power on, the screen remains blank. Is it possible for the commands above to do that? Is it possible to recover?
I hear the power on chime and the ethernet connection shows a green status light, but I can't ping it.

One other thing I did prior was to install gnome. I couldn't log in so I switched back to terminal mode and did a reboot. That worked fine. The display connected to the Mac Mini show a terminal screen. I then continued my work through an ssh connection. I removed gnome and continued on my django install followed by zsh install where it froze on the reboot above.

### What I've tried

I rebooted, waited for the chime and held down fn + F1 on a Apple keyboard. I also tried just F1. The screen remains blank. Nothing is ever displayed.

I rebooted, waited for the chime and held down ctrl + opt + F2. I also tried ctrl + cmd + F2 ( I don't remember which is alt). I got the same non response.

I'm pretty sure I still have the original OS image on a USB drive. I can't view the contents because MacOS doesn't recognize the formatting. I plugged each one in one at a time and rebooted to no effect. It's been years since I imaged it so I don't remember the process.

I also tried the above with a non-mac keyboard.

Comment: I'm leaning toward the gnome uninstall being the cause here.  Can you get it to boot in command line only?

Comment: I can see how switching your login shell to `/bin/zsh` might result in failure to log in (e.g. if `/bin/zsh` did not get added to the `/etc/shells` file) but it's hard to see how it would result in the screen remaining blank

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I cannot comment on your post because of my reputation,

Try the following  keyboard shortcuts <kbd>F1</kbd>(while booting) and after being booted <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or other function keys <kbd>F3</kbd> and so on `but not` <kbd>F1</kbd> that's the default one

Comment: F1 doesn't work. I'm using a Mac keyboard. It does have an fn key. I tried fn + F! and just F1.

Comment: what about just `ctrl`+`alt`+`f2`